# react not rendering SearchBar component.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, components

I am attempting to have the SearchBar component render on index.html via index.js, but [image]whenever I run my server, I receive the following error "Uncaught ReferenceError: SearchBar is not defined" I believe my syntax is sound and don't know what could cause this error. Screenshots below:

The first image is of my index.js 
The second picture is of search_bar.js

[image]

Comment: You created the component as `Searchbar` and exported it as default as `SearchBar`

Comment: you have a typo on component declaration. change Searchbar to `const SearchBar = ` (capital `B`)

Comment: @AndreasT I believe the typo may be the problem. The typo was definitely the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes when you see "not defined" errors usually are typos

Comment: @thismarcoantonio thank you as well for pointing out the typo